# Нужны ли кавычки? (5)

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

***— Как понять предикативные основы?***

***— («)Грамматические(») то бишь.***

Нужны ли кавычки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да.

*— Как понять предикативные основы?*

*— «Грамматические» то бишь.*

Замена есть.

*— Как понять предикативные основы?*

*— Я имел в виду «грамматические».*